# What is this "100% accept rate" on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, accept-rate

What is this "100% accept rate" that appears under my name and avatar?
What does it mean?
I was unable to find a reference to it in the back-end of this site.

Comment: Check that out, two edits but it says **4 revisions**

Comment: Your revisions are worth more random. :) I wonder if it counts the migration from SO to here as 1? Not sure on the other 1.

Comment: Ok, random, counting: posting question (1), turn into CW during 5 minutes period (2), migrated to Meta (3), your edit (4). Easy, isn't it ;) Counting is like compiling statistics...

Comment: @Smithers Looks like the maths is strong in you.

Answer (score 7):

You have accepted answers for all of your questions, that have an answer. In your case for 62 out of 62.